# Try-Catch-Finally execution order

Tags: java, execution, try-catch-finally

Here is the code to demonstrate my point (java):

```
public static int getSize(List<String> list)
{
    System.out.println("begin");
    try
    {
        System.out.println("get list size");
        return list.size();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("exception");
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("finally");
        return -1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    List<String> list = null;
    int size = getSize(list);
    System.out.println("list size: " + size);
}
```

I expected the output of:

```
begin
get list size
exception
finally
list size: -1
```

instead I get other stuff and the one above as well... like the exception can show before get list size and after exception...

e.g.

> ```
> begin
> exception
> get list size
> finally
> list size: -1
> ```

and

> ```
> begin
> get list size
> finally
> exception
> list size: -1
> ```

Why is it doing this? What is the correct output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.out and System.err are differents stream.
The test is displayed when the strem flush. As they are differents, you can't be sure of when each flush will happen.
Try to display the exception in System.out and see the difference.